# Analyzing Memory dump for High CPU usage shows calls to Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Storage.ConfigurationChangeWatcher

Tags: .net, multithreading, cpu-usage, enterprise-library-6

I am analyzing memory dumps for high CPU usage but all I see is most of the runaway threads show a constant time of  0 days 0:05:48.921 the second and millisecond change offcourse and mostly all call the Microsoft Practices EnterpriseLibrary ConfigurationChangeWatcher. We are using MS Ent Lib 6 for logging. I do not understand how would that all be related to High CPU usage can anyone help me analyze the dumps and throw some light.

Child SP               IP Call Site
000000581c2ddeb0 00007ffb58790b2a [GCFrame: 000000581c2ddeb0] 
000000581c2ddf80 00007ffb58790b2a [GCFrame: 000000581c2ddf80] 
000000581c2ddfb8 00007ffb58790b2a [HelperMethodFrame: 000000581c2ddfb8] System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(System.Object)
000000581c2de0b0 00007ffaf0046f8a System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Change(UInt32, UInt32)
000000581c2de120 00007ffaf0ab0047 System.Timers.Timer.set_Enabled(Boolean)
000000581c2de180 00007ffaf1bf3edb Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Storage.ConfigurationChangeWatcher.pollTimer_Elapsed(System.Object, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
000000581c2de1d0 00007ffaf1bf3ea1 Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Storage.ConfigurationChangeWatcher.pollTimer_Elapsed(System.Object, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
000000581c2de220 00007ffaf1bf395f System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(System.Object)
000000581c2de2a0 00007ffaf049e7b2 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
000000581c2de370 00007ffaf049cb67 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
000000581c2de3a0 00007ffaf0a13c69 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
000000581c2de400 00007ffaf0a1390a System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
000000581c2de450 00007ffaf0a1c079 System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
000000581c2de4b0 00007ffaf0a19c48 System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
000000581c2de928 00007ffb4f3f4073 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 000000581c2de928] 
000000581c2deab8 00007ffb4f3f4073 [ContextTransitionFrame: 000000581c2deab8] 
000000581c2decd8 00007ffb4f3f4073 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 000000581c2decd8]

Child SP               IP Call Site
000000581b73e1e8 00007ffb5879195a [InlinedCallFrame: 000000581b73e1e8] Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.GetFileAttributesEx(System.String, Int32, WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA ByRef)
000000581b73e1e8 00007ffaefe84a3a [InlinedCallFrame: 000000581b73e1e8] Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.GetFileAttributesEx(System.String, Int32, WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA ByRef)
000000581b73e1c0 00007ffaefe84a3a DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(System.String, Int32, WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA ByRef)
000000581b73e280 00007ffaefe83d92 System.IO.File.FillAttributeInfo(System.String, WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA ByRef, Boolean, Boolean)
000000581b73e2f0 00007ffaefe83bc7 System.IO.File.InternalExists(System.String)
000000581b73e350 00007ffaefe81544 System.IO.File.InternalExistsHelper(System.String, Boolean)
000000581b73e390 00007ffaf0aafe51 Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Storage.ConfigurationChangeFileWatcher.GetCurrentLastWriteTime()
000000581b73e3c0 00007ffaf1bf3e18 Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Storage.ConfigurationChangeWatcher.pollTimer_Elapsed(System.Object, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
000000581b73e410 00007ffaf1bf395f System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(System.Object)
000000581b73e490 00007ffaf049e7b2 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
000000581b73e560 00007ffaf049cb67 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
000000581b73e590 00007ffaf0a13c69 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
000000581b73e5f0 00007ffaf0a1390a System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
000000581b73e640 00007ffaf0a1c079 System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
000000581b73e6a0 00007ffaf0a19c48 System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
000000581b73eb18 00007ffb4f3f4073 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 000000581b73eb18] 
000000581b73eca8 00007ffb4f3f4073 [ContextTransitionFrame: 000000581b73eca8] 
000000581b73eec8 00007ffb4f3f4073 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 000000581b73eec8]

I see this pattern through out the call stack.

Comment: What is your code using that watcher? If it keeps modifying the config file which in turn triggers more change events, high CPU usage is not surprising.

Comment: Thanks for your response. No I am not calling or using watcher specifically in the code. But I am not sure what is triggering it to be called so many times. Not sure if it is the default behavior of Microsoft Practices EnterpriseLibrary if so then why some 100+ threads wait more then 5 mins on this watcher

Comment: then it would be rather painful a process afterwards, as EF is no longer in active development and its support model is not clear.